# How to change the html that the autocomplete function renders?

Tags: javascript, codemirror

Is there an option to change the  html of the autocomplete list that is rendered? I currently have the following autocomplete function:

```
function snippet(): void {
    CodeMirror.showHint(codemirror, function (): any {
      const cursor = codemirror.getCursor()
      const token = codemirror.getTokenAt(cursor)
      const start: number = token.start
      const end: number = cursor.ch
      const line: number = cursor.line
      const currentWord: string = token.string


      const list: any[] = snippets.filter(function (item): boolean {
        return item.text.indexOf(currentWord) >= 0
      })

      return {
        list: list.length ? list : snippets,
        from: CodeMirror.Pos(line, start),
        to: CodeMirror.Pos(line, end)
      }
    }, { completeSingle: false })
```

is there an option for me to loop trough the list that is returned and create the html?